# Handling multiple same properties with @ConfigurationProperties

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have `Properties` class with a few different beans. Values from `application.yaml`:

```
@Configuration
@Getter
@Setter
public class RabbitProperties {

    private String requestExchangeName;
    private String requestQueueName;
    private String responseExchangeName;
    private String deadLetterExchangeName;

    @Bean
    @ConfigurationProperties("rabbit-service.common-orders")
    public RabbitProperties commonOrdersRabbitProperties() {
        return new RabbitProperties();
    }

    @Bean
    @ConfigurationProperties("rabbit-service.metrics")
    public RabbitProperties metricsRabbitProperties() {
        return new RabbitProperties();
    }

    ...//more beans
}
```

I'm using this `Configuration` in another config class:

```
@Configuration
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class RabbitServiceConfig {

    private final RabbitProperties commonOrdersRabbitProperties;
    private final RabbitProperties metricsRabbitProperties;
    ...//about 15 similar fields

    
    @Bean("metricsRabbitService")
    public RabbitService getMetricsRabbitService(AmqpAdmin amqpAdmin, Client rabbitClient) {
        return new RabbitService(
                metricsRabbitProperties.getRequestExchangeName(),
                metricsRabbitProperties.getRequestQueueName(),
                metricsRabbitProperties.getResponseExchangeName(),
                metricsRabbitProperties.getDeadLetterExchangeName(),
                rabbitClient,
                amqpAdmin
        );
    }

    @Bean("commonOrdersRabbitService")
    public RabbitService getCommonOrdersRabbitService(AmqpAdmin amqpAdmin, Client rabbitClient) {
        return new RabbitService(
                commonOrdersRabbitProperties.getRequestExchangeName(),
                commonOrdersRabbitProperties.getRequestQueueName(),
                commonOrdersRabbitProperties.getResponseExchangeName(),
                commonOrdersRabbitProperties.getDeadLetterExchangeName(),
                rabbitClient,
                amqpAdmin
        );
    }
...//etc
```

I'm adding new `RabbitProperties` field almost every week, so now it already has about 15-20 kinda same fields. How can I get rid of these fields and put them to `Map` for example? Where should I put values for this `Map` and initialize it? What is the proper way to use `ConfigurationProperties` here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I've understood the question properly, you could define a `private final Map<String, RabbitProperties> rabbitPropertiesMap;` in the `RabbitServiceConfig` class instead of all the fields. All the `RabbitProperties` will be bounded in the map by injection, with key equals to bean name.

Another different approach would be to update the implementation of `RabbitProperties` with something like

```
@ConfigurationProperties("rabbit-service")
@Value
@ConstructorBinding
public class RabbitServiceProperties {

  Map<String, RabbitProperties> rabbitPropertiesMap;

  @Value
  static class RabbitProperties {

    String requestExchangeName;
    String requestQueueName;
    String responseExchangeName;
    String deadLetterExchangeName;
  }
}
```

this way everything under the root `rabbit-service` in the application.yml with the structure described will be discovered and bound.